# alternative FizzBuzz example error

Tags: c#, fizzbuzz

Been trying to solve this for 2 days now and I just can't get it to work! The programs layout has to stay the same (part of the challenge). Really bugging me and hoping somebody could shed some light...

I keep getting the following error:
Use of unassigned local variable 'countOfFizz'
Use of unassigned local variable 'countOfBuzz'
Use of unassigned local variable 'countOfFizzBuzz'
Use of unassigned local variable 'countOfPrime'

On these lines:

```
fb.IsFizz(input, countOfFizz);
fb.IsFizz(input, countOfBuzz);
fb.IsFizz(input, countOfFizzBuzz);
fb.IsFizz(input, countOfPrime);
```

and here is the full code. (again apologies if its poor coding, its basics and the layout has been supplied already).

```
class FizzBuzz
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int input;
        string enter;
        int countOfFizz;
        int countOfBuzz;
        int countOfFizzBuzz;
        int countOfPrime;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
        enter = Console.ReadLine();
        input = int.Parse(enter);

        while (input != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
            enter = Console.ReadLine();
            input = int.Parse(enter);

            FizzBuzz fb = new FizzBuzz();
            fb.IsFizz(input, countOfFizz);
            FizzBuzz fb1 = new FizzBuzz();
            fb1.IsBuzz(input, countOfBuzz);
            FizzBuzz fb2 = new FizzBuzz();
            fb2.IsFizzBuzz(input, countOfFizzBuzz);
            FizzBuzz fb3 = new FizzBuzz();
            fb3.IsPrime(input, countOfPrime);
            FizzBuzz fb4 = new FizzBuzz();
            fb4.TotalFizz(countOfFizz);
            FizzBuzz fb5 = new FizzBuzz();
            fb5.TotalBuzz(countOfBuzz);
            FizzBuzz fb6 = new FizzBuzz();
            fb6.TotalFizzBuzz(countOfFizzBuzz);
            FizzBuzz fb7 = new FizzBuzz();
            fb7.TotalPrime(countOfPrime);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
    }

    public bool IsFizz(int input, int countOfFizz)
    {
        if (input % 9 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fizz");
            countOfFizz++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsBuzz(int input, int countOfBuzz)
    {
        if (input % 13 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Buzz");
            countOfBuzz++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsFizzBuzz(int input, int countOfFizzBuzz)
    {
        if (input % 9 == 0 && input % 13 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FizzBuzz");
            countOfFizzBuzz++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsPrime(int input, int countOfPrime)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < input; i++)
        {
            if (input % i == 0 && i != input)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Prime");
        countOfPrime++;
        return true;
    }

    public void BeginTesting(int countOfFizz, int countOfBuzz, int countOfFizzBuzz, int countOfPrime)
    {
        countOfFizz = 0;
        countOfBuzz = 0;
        countOfFizzBuzz = 0;
        countOfPrime = 0;
    }

    public int TotalFizz(int countOfFizz)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Fizz: ");
        return countOfFizz;
    }

    public int TotalBuzz(int countOfBuzz)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Buzz: ");
        return countOfBuzz;
    }

    public int TotalFizzBuzz(int countOfFizzBuzz)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of FizzBuzz: ");
        return countOfFizzBuzz;
    }

    public int TotalPrime(int countOfPrime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Prime: ");
        return countOfPrime;
    }

}
```

Comment: The error is clear. You're *not initializing your `countOf` variables before you use them. You declare them, and then use them and increment the value, but they need to be initialized before you start using them. Please learn to actually **read** the words in the error message. They almost always mean something.

Comment: _programs layout has to stay the same_ - Why? It's dreadful. Whoever set this really needs to go on a course themselves!

Comment: the static void main is my own doing! all i got was a layout full of empty methods and had to do the rest myself!

Comment: You shouldn’t need to create a new `FizzBuzz` instance for *every* single check in *every* iteration. Just use *one* instance for everything. Also, did those methods really have those `countOfX` parameters predefined, so you cannot get rid of them? (Can you maybe show you there original code you were given?)

Comment: What are you allowed to change?  What was the original layout they require you to keep?

Comment: i can post the original code but i'd feel almost as if i were cheating!

Comment: also the countOfX parameters can be changed, i was using them purely to get a count!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are passing `int`s to the methods, when an `int` (or `float`, `bool`, etc.) is passed to a method **it is copied, it is not passed as a reference variable**. Therefore, the `countOfBuzz` you change within a method is not the same as the one in the `main` method.

To solve this, don't pass those parameters to the methods. Instead, change the scope of those variables to be inside the class instead of inside the main method.

Also, it is good practice to initialize the variables to zero (local variables within methods **need** to be initialized, otherwise you get that message you asked about).

Answer (score 1):

As Simon already explained in his answer, integers are value types and all value types are always passed *by value* (by default). This means that when you call for example `IsFizz` with the `countOfFizz` then all that happens is that the *value* of that variable is passed to the function which then has its own variable with a copy of the value. So when the function changes the value, then only that local variable’s value changed but that change will never make it to the original variable.

One way to solve this would be to explicitely pass those variables *by reference*. You can do this by using `ref int countOfFizz` in the function signature for the parameter (i.e. add the `ref` keyword). However, I do *not* recommend you to do this as it will not provide a state the `FizzBuzz` class was likely to have.

So, in object oriented programming, you create objects which hold a *state*. In your case, the `FizzBuzz` is the class, the type of those objects. Now if we think about it, and take into account that you apparently want to keep count of the number of Fizz/Buzz/FizzBuzz cases, it makes sense to have those counts contained *within* the object.

So first of all, you should make those `countOfX` variables *instance variables* that are bound to the object.

Looking at the `IsFizz` etc. methods, they are all supposed to return a boolean value. So it’s likely that they were originally only meant to check the input and return true or false depending on if the check succeeded or not. Here we can also increment our counters when we find a falue. So in the end, those methods should only take the input, perform the check, increment their counter and return the check result.

The `TotalX` methods can then simply return the current counter results, while the BeginTesting method can reset them to zero (without taking any parameters).

Finally, in the Main function you want to create only a single instance of `FizzBuzz` so we can share the state during the whole duration of the program. You should check the return values for the `IsX` methods and print the appropriate response here (often you don’t want class types to arbitrarily print stuff but handle that in a different layer—in your case the console application that happens in the Main function).

As a final note, I would like you to know that I’m interpreting a lot into the original task here and cannot perfectly say what the original intention behind this code was. From my point of view it looks a bit ridiculous to do it like that. The FizzBuzz problem, even in this changed instance, is a simple problem aimed to show if a person is capable of *basic programming-related thinking*. It’s not necessarily meant to be a problem to work on in a complex object oriented manner, but just like the typical “Hello World” there seem to be people who like over-generalizing it in a way to make it terribly complex for fun or practice. I’m not really agreeing that this FizzBuzz instance with that predefined base code is either generalized nor fun nor a good practice. But again, this is just my opinion.

And finally a last hint to complete this “correctly”: The output “FizzBuzz” is the combination of both conditionals for “Fizz” and ”Buzz”. Meaning that if a number qualifies for “FizzBuzz” it *also* does so for the individual ones. So you should make sure that the check for the individual ones either explicitely prevent the “FizzBuzz” combination to match, or you check for the combined one first and abort further checks if it matches.

Answer (score -1):

Initialize the variables might do the trick for you:

```
int countOfFizz = 0;
int countOfBuzz = 0;
int countOfFizzBuzz = 0;
int countOfPrime = 0;
```

Comment: Sure, this solves one thing. But the problem is bigger than this.

Comment: It answers the question; perhaps we shouldn't do the complete assignment, but instead help to get past the current roadblock.

Comment: Or maybe we could be actually nice and point out instead that OP’s thinking that ints will be passed by reference is not correct to begin with, so the whole idea behind the code is not correct.

Comment: @Jmc Generally, you are correct about that. From my point of view though, I didn't do the complete assignment (I provided no code at all). But I foresaw that if I only would give your answer, another roadblock would come shortly.

Comment: Ok :).  I think banging your head on a problem for a while helps you remember it later on though.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the parameter (countOfFizz) from IsFizz, and it should work. Do the same for other similar methods.

```
public bool IsFizz(int input)
{
    if (input % 9 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fizz");
        countOfFizz++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The variables are declared in the *static* main method.